I I realized I forgot to make two sajdas in the last rakah while in second tashahud
As-salam alaykum, I couldn't find anything that answered my questions so here's what happened. today while I was praying salat al dhur during the last rakah i had doubts wether i made two sajdahs or one sajdah at first i thought it was just wiswas so i ignored it but i started thinking about it and i realized i might have i actually made one sajdah.
I was already in the second tashahhud so I made sujood al sahw right before taslim
do I have to pray my salah again?

It is not sufficient to come with sujud sahw if you had doubts about the amount of sujud you have performed. You rather must count the minimum as "performed" and come up with what you think is missing.
This can clearly be deduced from the hadith

It was narrated that ‘Abdur-Rahman bin ‘Awf said:
“I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: ‘If anyone of you is uncertain as to whether he has prayed one or two Rak’ah, let him assume it is one. If he is uncertain as to whether he has prayed two or three, let him assume it is two. If he is uncertain as to whether he has prayed three or four, let him assume it is three. Then let him complete what is left of his prayer, so that the doubt will be about what is more. Then let him prostrate twice while he is sitting, before the Taslim (saying the Salam).’”
(Sunan abn Majah)

In other words, if you are in the tashahud you need nevertheless to stop it at once and perform the missing sujud and then (when you) conduct the last tashahhud and follow it with the sujud as-sahw now the madhhabs have differences on whether you should perform the sujud as-sahw before or after the tasleem:
Imam Muslim in his sahih quoted five major ahadith (or cases) on the topic of sujud as-sahw:

on the authority of abu Hurrairah only confirms the amount of sujud as-sahw and doesn't say when to perform it.
on the authority of abu Buhaina where the missing of the 1st tahsahud after the second raka' is missing before standing up, but when finishing the prayer after tashahhud sujud as-sahw was performed before tasleeem.
on the authority of abu Sa'id al-Khudri on doubts on how much one prayed in which sujud as-sahw was also performed before tasleem.
on the authority of 'Abdullah ibn Masu'd where standing up for the 5th raka' is mentioned and sujud as-sahw was performed after tasleem.
The hadith known as hadith dhual-Yadayn in which the imam has stood up after tasleem of (only) two raka'a and the audience and him spoke and then correction of the prayer by sujud as-sahw after tasleem.

Imam Ahmad and the Dahiri's considered the sujud as-sahw applicable only in the cases mentioned above as mentioned without the application of qiyas to other cases.
The Malikis say: if the incorrect prayer was missing something you must perform the sujud before the tasleem, if it was adding something to the prayer you must perform it after the tasleem. Imam an-Nawawi regarded this opinion as the strongest.
The Hanfis say: you should perform sujud as-sahw always after tasleem.
The Shafi'is say: you should perform sujud as-sahw always before tasleem. However, -as an-Nawawi mentioned in his commentary on Sahih Muslim (see here in Arabic)- there's another view of a-Shafi'i saying similar to his teacher Malik.
Note
In case of sujud as-sahw after tasleem there's also a difference of opinion whether a tahshhud is necessary before performing tasleem.
See also:
What is the correct manner to perform sujud sahw?
How to continue prayer if one found out he missed or added a rak'a or a part of the rak'a?
